# MongoDB Multidimensional Arrays Flatten In Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, multidimensional-array, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following doc:

```
{ 
"items" : [
    [
        {
            "itemID" : "arSiPKXhqAXQ8MwMA", 
            "name" : "Item number 1", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(56)
        }, 
        {
            "itemID" : "xmuZT4u7o6YPQ87Bf", 
            "name" : "Item number 2", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(55)
        }
    ], 
    [
        {
            "itemID" : "QjvcodRRK8dBeAzyh", 
            "name" : "Item number 1", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(80), 
            "side" : NumberInt(147), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(68)
        }, 
        {
            "itemID" : "jaQ3o6ba6dwNv38Bm", 
            "name" : "Item number 2", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(98), 
            "side" : NumberInt(138), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(88)
        }
    ], 
    [
        {
            "itemID" : "ZPrSr5LZJt7mQP9KM", 
            "name" : "Item number 1", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(141), 
            "side" : NumberInt(138), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(70)
        }, 
        {
            "itemID" : "qR5qsyzfbAgqcvA84", 
            "name" : "Item number 2", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(69), 
            "side" : NumberInt(148), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(99)
        }
    ], 
    [
        {
            "itemID" : "XrTEua9rRgieGyDo4", 
            "name" : "Item number 1", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(62)
        }, 
        {
            "itemID" : "GT4d9kdNSn9AikjBF", 
            "name" : "Item number 2", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(62)
        }
    ], 
    [
        {
            "itemID" : "cPEN7fnt9CG3zAFES", 
            "name" : "Item number 1", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(104)
        }, 
        {
            "itemID" : "2z4KER4JR8iY3CAst", 
            "name" : "Item number 2", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(57)
        }
    ], 
    [
        {
            "itemID" : "Csq6DbLrmFA4h8FdS", 
            "name" : "Item number 1", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(78)
        }, 
        {
            "itemID" : "4BpZPss5ueJHYg2g9", 
            "name" : "Item number 2", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(108)
        }
    ], 
    [
        {
            "itemID" : "abMCndutq2gMtMpC3", 
            "name" : "Item number 1", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(109), 
            "side" : NumberInt(50), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(103)
        }, 
        {
            "itemID" : "sZTtYi8AMrXWRyHM2", 
            "name" : "Item number 2", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(128), 
            "side" : NumberInt(66), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(87)
        }
    ], 
    [
        {
            "itemID" : "6bwLiurf5D5oziLmF", 
            "name" : "Item number 1", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(125), 
            "side" : NumberInt(79), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(75)
        }, 
        {
            "itemID" : "esmvcWMeNbZXzFjSg", 
            "name" : "Item number 2", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(98), 
            "side" : NumberInt(132), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(51)
        }
    ], 
    [
        {
            "itemID" : "AibkKHbpdESHM47fv", 
            "name" : "Item number 1", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(67), 
            "side" : NumberInt(82), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(72)
        }, 
        {
            "itemID" : "TpsaYTST536hm4BLx", 
            "name" : "Item number 2", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(148), 
            "side" : NumberInt(92), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(69)
        }
    ], 
    [
        {
            "itemID" : "R8iNca43bTc97DKgG", 
            "name" : "Item number 1", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(50)
        }, 
        {
            "itemID" : "v7x4yKFFF5vPjLTWb", 
            "name" : "Item number 2", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(63)
        }
    ], 
    [
        {
            "itemID" : "XAFpcujePnKHMq3et", 
            "name" : "Item number 1", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(124), 
            "side" : NumberInt(87), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(50)
        }, 
        {
            "itemID" : "BLA2azuv2FboStGKo", 
            "name" : "Item number 2", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(122), 
            "side" : NumberInt(83), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(71)
        }
    ], 
    [
        {
            "itemID" : "2urB3BRLjZWjaHrEp", 
            "name" : "Item number 1", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(72)
        }, 
        {
            "itemID" : "B5Nurs4CXmzQnQ9Zg", 
            "name" : "Item number 2", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(78)
        }
    ], 
    [
        {
            "itemID" : "itjB327N8drTZxKx9", 
            "name" : "Item number 1", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(84)
        }, 
        {
            "itemID" : "6YzDgcvkfoAf9nLpf", 
            "name" : "Item number 2", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(107)
        }
    ], 
    [
        {
            "itemID" : "AdhS2TuHj93eyQ8mC", 
            "name" : "Item number 1", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(71)
        }, 
        {
            "itemID" : "NSBbbKqioTCfC3yAp", 
            "name" : "Item number 2", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(51)
        }
    ], 
    [
        {
            "itemID" : "vZXifWuiDeTgJiR8z", 
            "name" : "Item number 1", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(60)
        }, 
        {
            "itemID" : "y5SLnS5qjKQWcNqC3", 
            "name" : "Item number 2", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(73)
        }
    ], 
    [
        {
            "itemID" : "K8i4FveNeDMknuHe2", 
            "name" : "Item number 1", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(95), 
            "side" : NumberInt(139), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(94)
        }, 
        {
            "itemID" : "jfRqG7o6GvHxqR7XB", 
            "name" : "Item number 2", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(52), 
            "side" : NumberInt(67), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(62)
        }
    ], 
    [
        {
            "itemID" : "AeWX8ycx8Kxx5fs9j", 
            "name" : "Item number 1", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(58)
        }, 
        {
            "itemID" : "zB4fvrkHtKuLqfFdT", 
            "name" : "Item number 2", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(107)
        }
    ], 
    [
        {
            "itemID" : "k4MAXcqv6M4CNbyqK", 
            "name" : "Item number 1", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(53)
        }, 
        {
            "itemID" : "sKtNyWfp8LQmFdDhg", 
            "name" : "Item number 2", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(106)
        }
    ], 
    [
        {
            "itemID" : "WxEmSxJzmiuiiZF6e", 
            "name" : "Item number 1", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(63)
        }, 
        {
            "itemID" : "DJdncCq5apwr8RZbg", 
            "name" : "Item number 2", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(77)
        }
    ], 
    [
        {
            "itemID" : "hRpGE9RBt8zKuGNWo", 
            "name" : "Item number 1", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(89)
        }, 
        {
            "itemID" : "5eYvckNjWL6QnnroF", 
            "name" : "Item number 2", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(87)
        }
    ], 
    [
        {
            "itemID" : "kCugbteCN3zYnpsQe", 
            "name" : "Item number 1", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(72)
        }, 
        {
            "itemID" : "cBmT5HHQSfGHsjxW4", 
            "name" : "Item number 2", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(79)
        }
    ], 
    [
        {
            "itemID" : "N7xzob86NNDtzti5W", 
            "name" : "Item number 1", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(92)
        }, 
        {
            "itemID" : "j4xrE2gaKdJYv2BuN", 
            "name" : "Item number 2", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(102)
        }
    ], 
    [
        {
            "itemID" : "jhnr5wNiRQFR2fCZy", 
            "name" : "Item number 1", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(103)
        }, 
        {
            "itemID" : "JYaJZhYcrFnzQAwQ2", 
            "name" : "Item number 2", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(94)
        }
    ], 
    [
        {
            "itemID" : "sc7pYWMhKfHZLydCC", 
            "name" : "Item number 1", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(53)
        }, 
        {
            "itemID" : "K9qTTmeWHPt8d7Zwy", 
            "name" : "Item number 2", 
            "complexDrink" : false, 
            "real" : NumberInt(0), 
            "side" : NumberInt(0), 
            "projected" : NumberInt(99)
        }
    ]
],
```

}

I would like to return all the items in 1 array, without using `$unwind`. and I have to do it in the `$project` stage. how would I do it? I tried

```
db.getCollection.aggregate([
{
  $match: {
    registerID: { $in: [ObjectId("7e343dadb3ded2eb83db3bb0"), ObjectId("018039aab7a39d32b573ae43")] },
    timestamp: {
      $gte: ISODate('2017-01-10T00:00:00+01:00'),
      $lte: ISODate('2017-01-10T23:59:59+01:00'),
    }
  }
 },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: '$registerID',
          items: { $push: '$items' }
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          'items': {
             $map: {
               input: '$items',
               as: 'item',
               in: '$$item'
             }
           },
        },
    },
      {
        $sort: {
          timestamp: 1,
        },
      },
])
```

Answer (score 0):

add this stage to your pipeline

```
{
    items: {
            $map: {
                input: "$items",
                as: "itemList",
                in: {$arrayElemAt: ["$$itemList", 0]}
            }
    }
}
```